# Creating and Getting values from tkinter check boxes using for loop

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, checkbox, tkcalendar

This code is a part of my project in which I have to manage the attendance of 50 (or more) students.

The thing I want is that all the checkboxes should initially be 'checked' *(showing the present state)* and when I uncheck random checkboxes *(to mark the absent)* and click the `Submit` button *(yet to be created at the bottom of the window)*, I should get a list with 'entered date' as first element and the roll numbers i.e. 2018-MC-XX as other elements.

**For example:** `['01/08/2020', '2018-MC-7', '2018-MC-11', '2018-MC-23', '2018-MC-44']`

Actually my plan is when I will get a list I will easily write it to a text file. Also, if there is another way of creating multiple scrollable checkboxes without packing them inside a canvas then please do tell!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

root = Tk()
root.geometry('920x600+270+50')
root.minsize(920,600)

Attendance_frame = Frame(root)    ### Consider it a Main Frame
Attendance_frame.pack()

attendaceBox = LabelFrame(Attendance_frame, text = 'Take Attendance', bd = 4, relief = GROOVE, labelanchor = 'n',font = 'Arial 10 bold', fg = 'navy blue', width = 850, height = 525)     # A Label Frame inside the main frame

attendaceBox.pack_propagate(0)
attendaceBox.pack(pady = 15)

dateFrame = Frame(attendaceBox)    # A small frame to accommodate date entry label & entry box
dateFrame.pack(anchor = 'w')

font = 'TkDefaultFont 10 bold'
date_label = Label(dateFrame, text = 'Enter Date : ', font = font).grid(row = 0, column =  0, sticky = 'w', padx = 10, pady = 10)

date_entry = DateEntry(dateFrame, date_pattern = 'dd/mm/yyyy', showweeknumbers = FALSE, showothermonthdays = FALSE)
date_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'w')

noteLabel = Label(attendaceBox, text = 'Note: Uncheck the boxes for absentees').pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 10, pady = 5)

canvas = Canvas(attendaceBox, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
checkFrame = Frame(canvas, width = 100, height = 50)
vsb = Scrollbar(canvas, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.pack_propagate(0)
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=checkFrame, anchor="nw")

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

checkFrame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

for i in range(0,51):     # A loop to create Labels of students roll numbers & names
    c = Checkbutton(checkFrame, text = f"{'2018-MC-'+str(i+1)}       Student {i+1}")
    c.grid(row = i, column = 0, padx = 10, sticky = 'w')


mainloop()
```

Comment: can u explain in simple terms what u expect vs wt u got

Comment: First you need `StringVar` for each `Checkbutton` in order to get the state of the `Checkbutton` later.  Then you can use a list to hold the `StringVar`s  so that you can access them later.  You can set the `onvalue` of the checkbuttons to the roll number associated to them.

Comment: You can use `Text` widget to hold the checkbuttons (using `Text.window_create()` to insert the checkbuttons into the `Text` box).

Comment: @acw1668 can you please explain it with a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need `StringVar` for each Checkbutton in order to get the state of the `Checkbuttons` later. Then you can use a list to hold the `StringVars` so that you can access them later. You can set the `onvalue` of the `checkbuttons` to the roll number associated to them.

Also you can use `Text` widget instead of `Canvas`+`Frame`.  Below is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

text = tk.Text(frame, width=40, height=20)
text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)

vars = []
for i in range(51):
    rollnum = '2018-MC-'+str(i+1)
    var = tk.StringVar(value=rollnum)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=rollnum, variable=var, onvalue=rollnum, offvalue='', bg='white')
    text.window_create('end', window=cb)
    text.insert('end', '\n')
    vars.append(var)

vsb = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=text.yview)
vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

text.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

def submit():
    # extract roll numbers for checked checkbuttons
    result = [var.get() for var in vars if var.get()]
    print(result)

tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```